# Types of Collapsing Forcing Notions

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I am interested in different types and properties of ways to make some inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$ the new $\omega_2$. So a way of collapsing every $\alpha<\kappa$ to be of cardinallity $\aleph_1$, while preserving $\omega_1$ and $\kappa$ (and probably everything above $\kappa$).

A major example is of course the Levy collapse, which is $\sigma-$closed and homogeneous (and also has nice quotients with regard to those properties)

Another nice one is Itay Neeman's side condition poset - working with finite $\in$-increasing and closed under intersections chains of elementary submodels of $H(\kappa)$ which are either countable, or of the form $H(\alpha)$, for nice enough $\alpha$. This poset also collapses every cardinal between $\omega_1$ and $\kappa$, while preserving all other cardinals.

A useful property of that collapsing way is that it is (and it's quotients are) strongly proper, so they are not adding branches of length at least $\omega_1$ to trees from $V$.

I think I've read that one can do similar thing by iterating with countable support Sacks forcing (also yielding the tree property if going up to a weakly compact cardinal), but I am not sure of the details.

Are there other ways of collapsing cardinals in that way, and are there any special properties of those forcing notions (like $\sigma-$closure, homogeneity and strong properness in the case of the two examples given above)?

Comment: In general if you just iterate with countable support a "generic enough" family of forcings which are not going to collapse $\omega_1$, you will end up unboundedly often collapsing whatever the current $\omega_2$ might be, so at the end $\kappa$ will be $\omega_2$, provided some chain conditions are kept.

Comment: I guess that at least true for an iteration that adds reals unboundedly many times? Or am I missing something basic?

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest.